# Java: multiple inner classes generated from Singleton Holder pattern

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, singleton

I have a pretty simple singleton that uses holder pattern (I've shown just the pattern, not other details):

```
public class Foo
{
    private static class FooHolder
    {
        private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }

    public static Foo getInstance()
    {
        return FooHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

When I compile this class through `Eclipse 1.6 compiler`, it generates two classes: `Foo.class` and `Foo$FooHolder.class`. But when I compile it through `Maven` and `JDK 1.6 compiler`, it generates an additional class: `Foo$1.class` and that class is pretty much empty.

I'm trying to understand why this happens. I cannot provide more details on code due to restrictions.

Comment: If you use Eclipse compiler you are using a different compiler as you might use in Maven via JDK 1.6...(depending on what you have configured)...without pom file etc. it's hard to guess...

Comment: Try changing the access of the field `INSTANCE` to default instead of private. Do you still get the extra class?

Comment: No, `javac` version 1.6.0_65 does not reproduce your report.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, the most likely scenario is that the extra anonymous inner class comes from the part of the code we're not allowed to see.

Comment: @biziclop I made both the inner class and field default accessible, and then the field default accessible and inner class private, but it still generated that extra class for both these cases.

Answer (score 2):

While java allows access to private members of other classes in the same `.java` the JVM doesn't support this.

Instead the compiler generates code which gives secret access to these member via generated accessor methods eg access$010() or generated sub - classes. Exactly how each compiler does it is an implementation detail.

I am pretty sure Oracle JDK 7 doesn't do this.

Btw, using an Enum instead world be simpler and create less classes.